# How to recoginize trial user?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, subscription

I'm trying to use android subscription system.
And I think setting up 7days trial.

I would like to summarize trial users and paid users separately.
I assume that my android app gets subscription status(trial/paid) from google play, then send it to my aggregation server.

But I couldn't find the way to discriminate the status with my client app.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to make a database table with the confirmation numbers for trial or paid? this can be connected to your web service online, once activated, you can have the confirmation key and status in a table and that way you can track the user?

but then you will have to have a code, that calculates, the days..

I am also new to android development, but if I had to do it I would do it this way.
or if someone is aware of a better way, then I would love to know it aswell..

but I still do not know you are asking for code or Idea of how can it be implemented..

Comment: Thank you for replying.I need an idea.Actually I thought about it(calculating the days), but trial period might be changed.

Comment: Yes, then keep a database of the users,
Example: ConfirmationID   Date Activated  - DaysLeft.. or you can put a second date field.. and then usertype
This can not be changed by the user, by the user, you can always check it when they try to open the application..